# How do you separate a HashMap onto separate lines using FileOutputStream?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap that I would like to write as separate lines to a text file. How do you go about doing this? In the SysOut above the code for writing to a text file I am printing out the values in the way that I would like to print them.

```
    map.forEach((k,v)-> System.out.println(k+", "+v));

    File file = new File(Constants.FILEPATH);

    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);  
    ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);          
    s.writeObject(map);
    s.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an `ObjectOutputStream`, use a `PrintWriter`:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file)) {
    map.forEach((k,v) -> out.println(k+", "+v));
}
```

Comment: That’s right. An `ObjectOutputStream` is for serialization, not for writing a human-readable file.

Comment: Did the job! Thank you